# Bootstrap3: Firefox bug - Cannot set div height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

Firstly here is the link: http://isotopethemes.com/extenso/home9.html

Everything is fine in chrome.In firefox the slider is pushed to right side, this happens because a **'nav.navbar.navigation-9'** height is 50px. 
I've set the height to 40px, while the page loads it shows 40px after it loads the height is back to 50px, hence the slider is pushed to right side.

I've tried all possible solutions I know, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `main-nav` height to 38px.

```
.header-9-navigation .main-nav {
    height: 38px;
    position: static;
}
```

Your main-nav have to equal with header-9-form then only the slider would appear below.